# Isomorphisms: $(Aut(V), \circ) \to (GL(n, \mathbb{R}), \cdot)$ and $(Or(V), \circ) \to (O(n), \cdot)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $V$ be a $n$-dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-vector space. Let $Aut(V)$ be the set of the automorphism on $V$. I have shown that this is a group with respect to the composition of functions. However, I don’t know how to work out the details of the proof that it is isomorphic (let us denote the isomorphism with $phi$) to the group of real invertible matrices of order $n$, $GL(n, \mathbb{R})$. I’ve figured out that I should associate each automorphism with its matrix with respect to a fixed basis $B$, but then I don’t know how to do the rest.

Also, let $g$ be a positive defined scalar product -- and therefore $(V,g)$ an Euclidean vector space. Let $Or(V)$ be the set of orthogonal transformations of $V$ and $O(n)$ the set of orthogonal matrices of order $n$. How can I prove that $Or(V)$ is a subgroup of $Aut(V)$ and $O(n)$ is a subgroup of $GL(n, \mathbb{R})$? I figure that $(Or(V), \circ)$ is isomorphic (with isomorphism a restriction and reduction of $\phi$, which we will denote with $\phi^*$) to $(O(n), \cdot)$;  can you show me the details of the proof of the statement?

Also, let us consider $SO(n)$, which is a subgroup of $O(n)$. Is it true that $\phi^{-1}SO(n)$ is a subgropup of $(Or(V), \circ)$?

---

From my book, I only know that a matrix $A$ is orthogonal iff $A^tA=AA^t= I$ and that, if $g$ is a scalar product, $o$ is an orthogonal transformation iff $g(o(v),o(u))=g(v,u)$.

Answer (score 1):

"I’ve figured out that I should associate each automorphism with its matrix with respect to a fixed basis B, but then I don’t know how to do the rest."

First, you need to show that the matrix corresponding to an automorphism is indeed invertible. It may help to remember that (a) a linear transformation from $V$ to itself is invertible iff it is injective and (b) a matrix is invertible iff its columns are linearly independent.

Next, you need to show that the association you described is bijective, i.e. that every invertible matrix corresponds to one and only one invertible linear transformation on $V$. It sounds like you are pretty much there on this part since you've described the correspondence between matrices and linear transformations.

In order to complete your proof you need to show that this association is a homomorphism, i.e. that if $f$ and $g$ are linear transformations and $M_f$ and $M_g$ are their matrices, then $M_{f \circ g} = M_fM_g$. To reiterate, you need to show that the multiplication of matrices corresponds to the composition of functions.

"How can I prove that O_r(V) is a subgroup of Aut(V) and O(n) is a subgroup of GL(n,ℝ)?"

Note that $O(n)$ is non-empty since it contains the identity matrix.

To prove that $O(n)$ is a subgroup, you first need to show that orthogonal matrices are invertible. You already noted that a matrix A is orthogonal (with respect to the Euclidean inner product) iff $A^tA=AA^t=I.$

Next, you need to show that if $A$ and $B$ are orthogonal, then $AB$ is orthogonal. Once again, you can use that condition of $A^tA=AA^t=I.$

Lastly, you need to show that the inverse of $A$ is orthogonal. Once you see that the inverse is $A^t$, this should follow from the fact that you noted.

You will then perform the corresponding steps for $O_r(V)$.

"I figure that (Or(V),∘) is isomorphic (with isomorphism a restriction and reduction of ϕ, which we will denote with ϕ∗) to (O(n),⋅); can you show me the details of the proof of the statement?"

This is true (at least if your scalar product is indeed the Euclidean scalar product). Since $\phi$ is injective, it suffices to show that $\phi$ is surjective, i.e. that the transformation corresponding to every orthogonal matrix is an orthogonal transformation. Suppose that $o$ is a linear transformation and that $A$ is a matrix. Then $g(o(v),o(u)) = <Av, Au> = (Au)^tAu.$ Now you can use the properties you've already listed to finish this proof.

"Also, let us consider SO(n), which is a subgroup of O(n). Is it true that ϕ−1SO(n) is a subgropup of (Or(V),∘)?"

More generally, if $\phi$ is a surjective homomorphism between two groups, is the pre-image of a subgroup a subgroup of a domain? Is it non-empty, closed under the group product, and closed under taking inverses? It may help to think in these terms.